# Program launchers suddenly do not respond in MATE

Tags: ubuntu-mate, mate-panel

Today when I turned on my computer running Ubuntu 20.04, Mate 1.24.0, I
encountered very curious behavior.  The top panel contains Application
Places System and various program launchers.  None of these respond to a
mouse click, neither left nor right.  However the icons on the right of the
top panel (network connections, speakers, calendar) work just fine.

I could not lauch Thunderbird, Firefox, nor anything in the left of the top
panel.  Placing the mouse in the middle of the screen and right clicking, I
got a popup menu which allowed me to launch a terminal.  Using this mechanism,
I could launch Thunderbird and Firefox, and they seem to work fine.

However, the bottom panel, which usually shows what apps are open, shows
nothing.  When I click the Show Desktop button at the far left of the bottom
panel, all visible windows disappear.  Another click and they reappear.  But,
if I click the Minimize button in an open window, it disappears and cannot
be brought back.

It is very awkward trying to work in this situation.  Any help is greatly
appreciated.

Comment: What significant things did you do on the computer before you turned it off the last time before the problem happened?

Comment: This morning everything works.  I have no idea what is going on.  I am going to leave this question in hopes that someone who understands the problem can enlighten me in case it happens again.